# Explain please the following statement from Naive Set Theory

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Here is a statement that I can't understand:

> Ordered triples, ordered quadruples, etc., may be defined as families whose
>   index sets are unordered triples, quadruples, etc.

For now, let's stick with the ordered triples. First of all I can't understand whether the index set is a set of unordered triples like $\{ \{a, b, c\}, \{d, e, f\}\}$ or it is itself an unordered triple?

Also, I just can't imagine how having any of such sets as the index set can help me to build a set of ordered triples. Maybe some example will make things clear. I will be very grateful if you help. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Where did you find this statement? Personally, I also find it difficult to parse ...

Comment: @NoahSchweber, Naive Set Theory of Halmos

Comment: What page? It's an entire book ...

Comment: @NoahSchweber, oh, sorry. Page 36 in "Families" section

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is a bit unclear.

Halmos' goal is to define the notion of an arbitrary Cartesian product. This should generalize the usual Cartesian product of *two* sets, $A\times B$, but should "work for any number of sets." Before diving into his description, let me point out that this really is nontrivial: how should we think of the Cartesian product of "$\mathbb{R}$-many" sets?

Halmos is about to tell us, essentially, that the Cartesian product of an indexed family $\{X_i\}_{i\in I}$ of sets is just the set of all indexed families $\{x_i\}_{i\in I}$ of objects with $x_i\in X_i$. Maybe more clearly, **an element of the Cartesian product is a function** with domain $I$; it sends $i\in I$ to the "$i$th coordinate," which must be in $X_i$.

---

To motivate this, Halmos has us go back to the idea of a Cartesian product. We can rethink Cartesian products as follows:

- Fix any two distinct sets, $a$ and $b$. We'll think of the first as "LEFT" and the second as "RIGHT."
- Now an ordered pair has two "coordinates," a left coordinate and a right coordinate. We're going to match these up with $a$ and $b$ above: if I have a function $z$ with domain $\{a, b\}$ such that $z(a)=x\in X$ and $z(b)=y\in Y$ *(here I write "$z(i)$" for Halmos's "$z_i$")*, we want to think of the object $z$ as **being** the ordered pair $(x, y)$. Informally, $z$ says

$$\mbox{My left coordinate is $x$, and my right coordinate is $y$.}$$

Put another way:

> We can think of the ordered pair $(x, y)$ as the function with domain $\{a, b\}$ (which is an unordered pair) mapping $a$ to $x$ and $b$ to $y$.

**This is easiest to think about if $a=0$ and $b=1$, or something similar,** but Halmos's point is that all we need is that the index set has two distinct elements. Now here's the key linguistic step Halmos makes which I think is confusing at first:

> An ordered pair **is** an indexed set! And the index*ing* set is $\{a, b\}$, which is an unordered pair.

Comment: are you sure you wanted to say **sets** in the end? "... that the Cartesian product of an indexed family $\{X_i\}_{i \in I}$ of sets is just the set of all indexed families $\{x_i\}_{i \in I}$ **of sets** with $x_i \in X_i$". Because as I understand, if we say the family $\{x_i\}$ of sets, its range consists of sets implying $x_i$ is a set which is, as I understand, is not said

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov My ZFC bias is showing. In [formal ZFC set theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zermelo%E2%80%93Fraenkel_set_theory) (and many other formal set theories), every object is in fact a set [and everything is "built out of" the emptyset in a sense](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2763341/is-mathematics-just-a-bunch-of-nested-empty-sets). But yes, in the context of Halmos's book that's inappropriate. Fixed!

Comment: Thanks for the great answer! So, to make an ordered triple, let's say, $(11, 21, 31)$ I need some unordered triple and let it be $\{a, b, c\}$, true? Then I have to have (actually I doubt this statement about having the following set, because I need to construct it additionaly, correct me if I am wrong) the family $\{X_i\}_{i \in \{a, b, c\}}$ and let it be $\{ (a,11), (b, 21), (c, 31)\}$. Then the Cartesian product of the family will be the set of all families $\{x_i\}$: $\{ \{ (a, 11), (b, 21), (c, 31)\} \}$, the element of which I interpret as the ordered triple we expected to make?

Comment: Not quite. The set $\{(a, 11), (b, 21), (c, 31)\}$ is *a single ordered triple*. The Cartesian product of three sets $X_a, X_b, X_c$ would be the *set of all* sets of the form $\{(a, x_a), (b,x_b), (c, x_c)\}$ with $x_a\in X_a, x_b\in X_b, x_c\in X_c$. So e.g. if $X_a=X_b=X_c=\mathbb{N}$, the set $\{(a, 11), (b, 21), (c, 31)\}$ would be *an element of* the Cartesian product, but the Cartesian product would also include other things like $\{(a, 18), (b, 467), (c, 3)\}$ (which we would think of as "$(18, 467, 3)$").

Comment: Oh, as $X_i$ is a set by itself the family $\{X_i\}_{i \in \{a, b, c\}}$ should look like  $\{(a, \{11\}), (b, \{21\}), (c, \{31\})\}$, assuming I only want to obtain a single ordered triple $(11, 21, 31)$?. And is it true, that I also need to construct the sets $X_i$ (for instance by axiom of specification or writing them on the paper to make sure about their existence) ?

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov No, that's still wrong. There are three things floating around here: (1) The family $\{X_i\}_{i\in\{a, b, c\}}$. If we ignore details for a moment, we can think of this as essentially the three-element set $\{X_a,X_b,X_c\}$. (2) The Cartesian product $Q=\prod_{i\in\{a,b,c\}}X_i$ (not quite in Halmos's notation). This is **a set of three-element sets**. $Q$ probably has *many more than three* elements; e.g. if each $X_i$ has two elements, $Q$ will have $2^3=8$ elements. (3) A single "ordered triple" in the Cartesian product $Q$ is a three-element set of the type described above.

Comment: As to the last sentence of your comment, yes, you need to have the sets $X_i$ "in hand" before you can talk about their Cartesian product.

Comment: Before reading further after $\{X_a, X_b, X_c\}$ I want to say that I can't agree with this. Becuase, as I understand, Halmos defines a family as a function which in its turn is a set of ordered pairs. That is why I write $\{(a, \{11\}), (b, \{21\}), (c, \{31\})\}$ and not $\{ \{11\}, \{21\}, \{31\} \}$.

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov Yes, that's why I said "if we ignore details for a moment." My point is just that the indexed family of $X_i$s is (generally) much "smaller" than their Cartesian product. If you prefer, I'm saying that $\{(a, X_a), (b, X_b), (c, X_c)\}$ has only three elements. The point is to distinguish it from the Cartesian product, and to distinguish both of those from *a single ordered triple* (= *element of* the Cartesian product).

Comment: So is it still wrong to write the family $\{X_i\}_{i\in\{a, b, c\}}$ as $\{(a, \{11\}), (b, \{21\}), (c, \{31\})\}$ where $X_a =\{11\}$, $X_b = \{21\}$, $X_c = \{31\}$?  (2) I understood what you say, that if at least one of $X_i$ has more than one elements in it like $X_a = \{11, 10\}$ then in the Cartesian product there will be more than one **three-element sets**, being exact $2 * 1 * 1 = 2$, assuming $X_b$ and $X_c$ both have one element.

Comment: @TurkhanBadalov I thought you were using my example where $X_a=X_b=X_c=\mathbb{N}$. If the $X_i$s are as you describe, then that's right.