# Give severeal examples for a set X such that each element of X is a subset of X.

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I recently started studying set theory and I have seen this exercise in the textbook. The only example I could think of was the empty set. This is how I think:

A number(for example 1), cannot be a subset of X since a number is not a set. So I need to have sets as the elements of X.

Then, I choose a element like $\{1\}$ for example. But then X must have the subset $\{1\}$, which means it has 1 as an element. This also cannot happen because of what I said before.

And even if choose an element of X as something like $\{\{\{\{1\}\}\}\}$, it will require $\{\{\{1\}\}\}$ to be an element of the set. Which then will require $\{\{1\}\}$ and eventually I come back to what I started with.

Can you show me what is wrong in the way I think of this problem, and can  you show some examples of these kinds of sets?

Comment: In the usual set theory formalism, a number *is* a set.

Comment: I think in the book I was studying it was not the case that a number is a set. Or at least nothing like that was mentioned so far. It was Cantor's set theory.

Comment: Well, if a number isn't a set, then what is it? The reason for the formalism is that you can encode the mathematical structures you'd like to consider using only sets.

Comment: Your analysis is working its way toward what's known as the Axiom of Foundation:  $\forall y \exists x \in y ~(x \cap y = \emptyset).$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your argument is right that there must not be any "urelements" hidden anywhere inside the set. But here are some examples:
$$\emptyset,\qquad\{\emptyset\},\qquad \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\},\qquad \{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\},\{\emptyset,\{\emptyset\}\}\} $$
and many more.

Note that if $S$ is a set with the desired property, then so is $S\cup\{S\}$.

Comment: It is worth pointing out the relation of this answer to the [set-theoretic definition of natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers).

Comment: Is this only possible using empty sets? Are there any other sets that I can use with the property you have given?

Comment: @RüzgarAyan you might be interested in reading this question:[Is mathematics just a bunch of nested empty sets?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2763341/is-mathematics-just-a-bunch-of-nested-empty-sets/)

Comment: @RüzgarAyan A transitive set not reachable by the method I described is $\{ \{\{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}\}, \{\{\{\emptyset\}\}\}, \{\{\emptyset\}\},\{\emptyset\},\emptyset\}$, but that too has nothing but emptyset at its "bones" - necessarily by the OP argument